# Product image/button missing in Magento Admin only on my computer

Tags: magento-1.9, image, upload

Using: **Magento v1.9.0.1** Browsers: **IE & Chrome on Windows**

I'm having an issue where none of the images and the Browse/Upload Button in the product admin are displaying for some reason. (see image for example)
[image]
Images/Buttons in admin missing

All the images are still in the media folder, they still exist in the database and they still show up on the frontend.

*One major confusing thing is they also show on our Local Server Computer*

I've tried various fixes but nothing worked, including:

1. Checked the Media folders exist and have the correct files
2. Checked the permissions on the folders
3. Renamed the .htaccess file in the media folder
4. Flash installed and working
5. JS/CSS file merge disabled

Any ideas how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: install or upgrade Flash player

Comment: I did and cleared cache

Answer (score 0):

Clear all cache and check in the private browser. No worry because it works on another pc, so the issue is your PC. Not your Magento.

Comment: I cleared cache, reindex. I know it is not magento but I am trying to figure what is preventing magento to dissapear the options